# optimizing a lookup task in ssis

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, lookup

I got this doubt about this kind of queries. I am migrating an ETL from Access to SSIS. One query involves an Inner Join with a table in an Oracle Database:

```
SELECT 
SQL_TABLE.COLUMN1,
SQL_TABLE.COLUMN2,
ORACLE_TABLE.COLUMN5,
ORACLE_TABLE.COLUMN6
FROM 
SQL_TABLE INNER JOIN ORACLE_TABLE ON
SQL_TABLE.ID_PPAL = ORACLE_TABLE.IDENTIF
WHERE
(((ORACLE_TABLE.COLUMN6) Is Not Null));
```

The issue is, the Oracle table has more than 18 million registers and the sql table has less than 300 records. The Inner Join should gives something like 2500 records as a result.

First I tried using a merge join task as you can see in the picture, but this is not efficient at all because of the characteristics of the tables, but looking for a possible situation someone proposed me using a look up task, but this only gives me one record for every match it founds, and this is not useful for me, I can not lose any record.

[image]

I wonder if is there another way to perform this query, because I can not believe that access would be more efficient than SSIS in this aspect.

Comment: did you join them perfectly using inner join only and check if there are any duplicate rows

Comment: Why do you say you can not lose any rows?  If you used to do this with an INNER join, only the matched rows would be returned, and all non-matching rows would be lost.   It should be possible to do this with a lookup if you implement it correctly.

Comment: The column identif in Oracle is not a PK, the PK in Oracle is composed , so, the Inner join with only this value can give me several results, but the lookup only gives me the first match.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the desired result.  In that case, no, you cannot use a Lookup to do what you want.   @Benjamin's answer is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience SQL Server will not optimize queries involving Oracle. The fastest approach I found was 1) Use Oracle Drivers to access data from SSIS. 2) Use fast load (with table lock) to load the Oracle table (with a where condition if appropriate) into a SQL Server Work Table. 3) Create a clustered index the table. 4) Do the join. If you are going to reuse the package you will want to truncate the work table and drop the index as the first two steps of the package.

Answer (score 0):

You should check any filters or try to do joins in Oracle database and thus leaking a little. If the result is incorrect, try using variables to store data and create scripts.

This can serve you:

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/ShawnHarrison/ssis/4579/looping-through-variable-values-with-a-foreach-loop-container